# Proper indentation of Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, indentation

I have written a Bash script which uses cases and functions for university, but no matter where I move the scripts, she says that they are not indented properly. What is the correct indentation of this sample of the script?

```
clear
      echo "Start A Process"
echo "*************************"
echo "1. Oxygen Level."
echo "***************************"
echo "2. Temperature ."
echo "*************************"
echo "3. Mars Rover Speed."
echo "*************************"
echo "4. Satellite Distance"
echo "*************************"
echo "5. Carbon Dioxide Level"
echo "*************************"
echo "6. Humidity %."
echo "*************************"
echo "Press A to quit."
echo "*************************"
    read -p "Please make a choice:" choice2

#Choices
case "$choice2" in

1)
$script/simulate start oxygen
echo "Oxygen Level Started."
sleep 5
;;
2)
```

Is there a website or a function on VMware where I can get my code automatically indented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indenting is done to *clarify* your code. Indentations are usually used for loops, if statements, function definitions to make it easy to see what statements are part of that loop or part of the if statement.

Another trick to make your code more readable is adding blank lines to separate out blocks of related code. For example, separating out your *menu* from the rest of your code with a couple of blank lines:

```
clear
echo "Start A Process"

echo "*************************"
echo "1. Oxygen Level."
echo "***************************"
echo "2. Temperature ."
echo ....   #And on and on...
echo "*************************"
echo "6. Humidity %."
echo "*************************"
echo "Press A to quit."
echo "*************************"

read -p "Please make a choice:" choice2

case "$choice2" in...
...
```

This makes it easier to see the menu you're presenting. You could also use a [Here document](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents) to eliminate the repeating echoes and quotation marks that make your menu hard to see. I'd would eliminate the over fancy stuff like the lines of asterisks. They don't add anything to the program and just make it harder to read - both code wise and execution wise:

```
clear

cat <<MENU
START A PROCESS
------------------
1. Oxygen Level.
2. Temperature .
3. Mars Rover Speed.
4. Satellite Distance
5. Carbon Dioxide Level
6. Humidity %.
A. Quit
------------------
MENU

read -p "Please make a choice:" choice2

case "$choice2" in...
...
```

Notice how using a *here document* makes your menu is easy to see and format.

Finally, your `case` statement should follow the indentation rule of keeping common lines indented, so you not only know the code that goes with the `case` statement, but that you also indent each choice:

```
case "$choice2" in
    1)
        $script/simulate start oxygen
        echo "Oxygen Level Started."
        sleep 5
        ;;
    2)
       .....
       .....
       ;;
   .....
esac
```

Some people will compact this a bit:

```
case "$choice2" in
    1)  $script/simulate start oxygen
        echo "Oxygen Level Started."
        sleep 5;;
    2)  .....
        .....;;
   .....
esac
```

The indentation is pretty much the same. A few lines are combined to make the `case` more compact and easier to read.

To help you with indentation and coding, use a program editor instead of just a text editor. A good program editor like VIM will automatically indent your code and even highlight the syntax making it easier to read. Eclipse is used for Java programming, but can be used as a text editor for shell scripts. A good editor can also help you with the way to use certain commands of statements by showing you the manpage for that command. When you press capital `K` in VIM, it will show you the manpage for that command.

Bash program *beautification* is quite tricky. However, there is a [Python program](http://arachnoid.com/python/beautify_bash_program.html) that will attempt the task.

Comment: what does that cat <<MENU do? How can I convert multiple submenus into this tiny format? I can post an edit of the whole menu code if you want. I also have a wildcard option in each menu in addition to the "A to quit."

Comment: It's called a *Here Document*, and I have a link in my answer explaining how it works. Did you read the link in the answer: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents. Or, did you not understand that example. Here's a Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells. Do a Google search for more information. Or do a search in StackOverflow to see some examples.

Comment: yes I think I have managed to get it going ok on my menu. you have of course mentioned that it looks tidier, is there any proof of it being faster or anything? I am using it in a project and would further like to justify my use of a heredoc rather than the echoes

Comment: I don't know if it's faster. A heredoc is easier to read in your code, and if you have to change the menu, it's easier to do. No need to worry about quotation mark balancing or that you typed `ehco` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

Just open the file with vim editor and typing gg=G will reindent the entire file.

Comment: I installed vim just for this. It's working.

Comment: Brilliant. I use `vim` on a daily basis and didn't know about this :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct indentation depends on the style desired, which is purely a matter of opinion.  In other words, the only person who can answer your question is the mysterious woman you refer to as "she".  Personally, I would say you have much bigger problems than indentation.  Rather than reading the selection from stdin, you ought to take it as a command line argument.  Rather than always printing a menu showing the options, you should only print them in response to -h or --help or something similar.  Rather than using a string of consecutive echos, use a single heredoc to print the menu. For example:

```
usage() {  cat <<- EOF
    $(basename $0) option

    Start A Process, where option is one of:
    1) oxygen level
    ...
    6) Humidity %.      
EOF
}
```

Comment: how can I do that tidily? Surely it is just a matter of preference? The document here on heredocs uses endless ifs and elses and is much messier in my opinion than the case menu. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Multiple if/elses are always a terrible idea.  I was just referring to using the heredoc to replace your echoes.  Editing answer with example.

Comment: the example in your answer implies that you have to use tabs for indentation (`<<-`  removes only leading tabs, not arbitrary whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

Style will always be a discussion. A good starting point is [Google's style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml) which also provides an overview of a lot of shell-constructions.

I happen to disagree with Googles style "Indent 2 spaces. No tabs.", I prefer tabs. Some developers like to see 2 spaces, some 4, and you can change it the way you like (vi: set tabstop=3 indent=3).

How to show a menu ?
You could use ONE echo like this:

```
   echo "Start A Process
       1. Oxygen Level.
       2. Temperature .
       3. Mars Rover Speed.
       4. Satellite Distance
       5. Carbon Dioxide Level
       6. Humidity %.

       Press A to quit."
```

When you have more menu's, I would consider using textfiles with the menu lines and `cat` the correct menu file. You can see an example at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38200/ksh-styling-text-based-menu-using-stderr/115371#115371

Comment: For years, the *standard* was to keep tabs at 8 characters and indents in most programming languages at 4 characters. (In VI, it's `set sw=4 ts=8`). Now, it's common to use spaces instead of tabs because it guarantees everyone reads it the way it should (what if someone sets tabs to 4 characters, your code will be off).  In VIM, you `set expandtab` or `set eb`. You can also `:retab` to expand tabs in an already existing file. For me, a mere two spaces is too little for me to be able to tell, especially in Python (but common in XML).

Answer (score 1):

This question has been treated on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39210/whats-the-standard-for-indentation-in-shell-scripts) already.

There is no such thing as a standard for Bash. Usually you indent at least each level of:

- functions
- loops (`for`, `while`)
- conditionals (`if`, `case`)

Some examples:

```
function echofoo() {
  echo foo
}
```

or

```
if true
then
  echo foo
else
  echo bar
fi
```

or

```
case "$choice" in
  1)
    echo foo
  ;;
  2)
    echo bar
  ;;
    [...]
```

Comment: what about the echoes? how should they be indented?

Comment: Indenting should make clear what control structure a command belongs to (i.e. _when_ it is executed). It is not so important, what type of command it is. So there is no special indent for `echo` statements, unless they are part of e.g. an `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

While there are no specific standards for shell script, universal indentation conventions dictate that commands on the same level of control should receive the same indentation, and commands which depend on the outcome from the control construct on the previous line should be indented relative to that control construct.  Where the control construct ends, the indentation should revert to that of the flow control construct.

So in your particular example, the indented `echo` and `read` statements are indented for no good reason relative to the commands which surround them, and the body of the `case` statement should be indented.

Most decent editors will do this more or less automatically for you if properly configured.

```
clear
# Really, really recommend turning this into a here document
echo "Start A Process"
echo "*************************"
echo "1. Oxygen Level."
echo "***************************"
echo "2. Temperature ."
echo "*************************"
echo "3. Mars Rover Speed."
echo "*************************"
echo "4. Satellite Distance"
echo "*************************"
echo "5. Carbon Dioxide Level"
echo "*************************"
echo "6. Humidity %."
echo "*************************"
echo "Press A to quit."
echo "*************************"
read -p "Please make a choice:" choice2

#Choices
case "$choice2" in
 1)
    $script/simulate start oxygen
    echo "Oxygen Level Started."
    sleep 5
    ;;
 2)
```

The specifics of the indentation inside the `case` statement are less rigid.  Some people indent the individual case labels back out to the same level as the governing `case`, others indent them a full level (here, four spaces).  I tend to choose a middle ground so that the body of a case is precisely four spaces indented relative to the governing `case` statement.

Comment: if I have a script with many echo style menus like this though, how can I turn them all into here documents? should I post the full menu as an edit above?

Comment: Hardly. Post a separate question if you really cannot figure out how to do it yourself; but @DavidW's answer already shows exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/39048/140047):

Emacs can do that:

- load the file into Emacs
- press `Ctrl-space` at the top of the file
- move the cursor to the bottom of the file
- press `Alt-x` and type `untabify` then return
- press `Alt-x` and type `indent-region` then return

This will get rid of tabs and indent everything properly.

If you need to do this more often and do not use Emacs as your editor, you might want to pack it all into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(setq require-final-newline 'visit)

(defun indent-files (files)
  (cond (files
         (find-file (car files))
         (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
         (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
         (save-buffer)
         (kill-buffer)
         (indent-files (cdr files)))))

(indent-files command-line-args-left)

;; EOF ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct indentation of this sample of the script?

There is none. Indentation is a matter of personal preference. If *she* suggests *your* code is not indented correctly you either missed a requirement or the instructions should be updated to state use of proper indentation is required.

> Is there a website or a function on VMware where I can get my code automatically indented?

No need to automate indentation. Just press the <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> keys to indent the code you copied.